# find fields of type String, Boolean, Integer using reflection

Tags: java

Is there a way to find fields in a class that are of the Type

```
    java.lang.Character.TYPE
    java.lang.Byte.TYPE
    java.lang.Short.TYPE
    java.lang.Integer.TYPE
    java.lang.Long.TYPE
    java.lang.Float.TYPE
    java.lang.Double.TYPE
```

there is a isPrimitive method for char, byte, short etc.

Comment: Couldn't you use Field#getType()?

Comment: Entire question has been mis-stated, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for one method that would return true for wrapper types. Springs ClassUtils provides one such method

```
ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(field.getType())
```

returns true for all of the above that I requested, except String

Comment: Then your entire question is incorrectly stated. Integer.TYPE is 'int', not a 'wrapper class'.

Answer (score 6):

You can start with [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) to get an array of the fields in your class. Then, iterate over each [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) in the array and filter as needed.

#### Something like this:

```
public static List<Field> getPrimitiveFields(Class<?> clazz)
{
    List<Field> toReturn = new ArrayList<Field>();

    Field[] allFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field f : allFields)
    {
        Class<?> type = f.getType();
        if (type.isPrimitive())
        {
            toReturn.add(f);
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

#### More info:

- [`Field#getType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29)
- [`Class#isPrimitive()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29) (though it sounds like you already know about this one)

---

### Edit

It might be worth clarifying that the types [`java.lang.Character.TYPE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#TYPE), etc., are the same thing as the class literals. That is,

- `java.lang.Character.TYPE == char.class`
- `java.lang.Byte.TYPE == byte.class`
- `java.lang.Short.TYPE == short.class`
- `java.lang.Integer.TYPE == int.class`
- `java.lang.Long.TYPE == long.class`
- `java.lang.Float.TYPE == float.class`
- `java.lang.Double.TYPE == double.class`

Answer (score 0):

Those types are all primitives, so use isPrimitive().

Comment: isPrimitive() on java.lang.Integer  returns false not true

Comment: Irrelevant. Integer.TYPE == int.class as pointed out by Matt Ball. 'int' is a primitive, and isPrimitive() will return 'true' for it. Integer.TYPE is *not* Integer.class.